# tax implications of reinvesting capital after selling house in india

Tags: india, capital-gains-tax, property-taxes

Say Person X is an NRI who has held a property in India for the past few years (greater than 3 years).

- sells property for a profit of 100 units
- As an NRI 100 units of profit gets taxed at 20%. 20 units are deducted via TDS

### questions

1. If the NRI reinvests the 100 units to buy another property within 6 months, can the NRI reclaim the entire amount (20%) in their return for that particular financial year ?
2. If the NRI sells the *new* property bought using capital **under 3 years for 110 units**
   , what will be the tax implications ?

```
I am under the impression that the you have to pay short term capital gains tax 

(income tax) on the profit (110 - 100 = 10 units), 

Is my understanding accurate ?
```

3. If the NRI sells the *new* property bought using capital **after 3 years for 110 units**
   what will be tax implications?

```
I am under the impression that the you have to pay long term capital gains tax 

20% on the profit (110 - 100 = 10 units), 

Is my understanding accurate ?
```